# Spectral radius in Banach algebra is commutative

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I want to show that for a Banach algebra $A$ and elements $x,y \in A$, we have
$$
r_A(xy) = r_A(yx),
$$
where $r_A$ is a spectral radius. This is how I am trying to do that:
$$
r_a(xy) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \| (xy)^n \| ^{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|x(yx)^{n-1} y \|^{\frac1n}.
$$
And this is where I stuck, since I only know that $\|xy\| \leqslant \|x\| \|y\|$. Could you please suggest any ideas on how to proceed with the proof?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $$\|x(yx)^{n-1}y\|^{1/n}\leq \|x\|^{1/n}\|(yx)^{n-1}\|^{1/n}\|y\|^{1/n}=\|x\|^{1/n}\|y\|^{1/n}(\|(yx)^{n-1}\|^{1/(n-1)})^{(n-1)/n}.$$
Now think about what happens as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: (+1), but [it would be more reader-friendly to be more explicit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614369) ;-)